# How to calculate the coordinate of a SVG object after rotation and scaling?

Tags: css, svg, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I wants to know the coordinates of a SVG object (i.e **ending x and y coordinates if starting x,y coordinates and height,widths are known to us**) after rotation and scaling of that SVG object.

Is there any way to calculate Ending coordinates of the SVG objects after rotation ?

If anybody knows please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Apply the transformation matrix to each co-ordinate

Comment: Do you know the starting x and y co-ordinate after applying rotation and trans?

Comment: if you have any fiddle then it will more helpful to me to understand problem

Answer (score 1):

**BBox method is helpful to get your starting and end point after or before applying the shape or object.**

```
You can select the object using d3 or jquery
        if you are using d3 the select in this way 
                    var rect = d3.select(selecteObject);
        if jquery then 
                   var rect = $(selecteObject);
                   var newx = rect.node().getBBox().x;
                   var newy = rect.node().getBBox().y;
                   var neww = rect.node().getBBox().width;
                   var newh = rect.node().getBBox().height;
                   var endCodinatex = newx + neww;
                   var endCodinatY = newy + newh;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Longson mentioned, you can apply the transformation matrix to each coordinate.

You can get the transformation matrix using the getCTM() method in the SVGLocatable interface.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable

For example, the following snippet applies the transformation matrix to the (x,y) coordinate of the rect element.

```js
var pointBefore = document.getElementById("pointBefore");
var pointAfter = document.getElementById("pointAfter");
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
var rect = document.getElementById("rect");
var ctm = rect.getCTM();
var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
p.x = rect.getAttribute("x");
p.y = rect.getAttribute("y");
pointBefore.textContent = p.x + ", " + p.y;
p = p.matrixTransform(ctm);
pointAfter.textContent = p.x + ", " + p.y;
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <rect id="rect" x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50" transform=" scale(2) rotate(15,50,50)"/>
</svg>
<p>point (before transform): <tspan id="pointBefore"></tspan></p>
<p>point (after transform): <tspan id="pointAfter"></tspan></p>
```